# Nginx + php-fpm on Amazon Linux = exited on signal 11

Tags: nginx, php

**Amazon Linux lastest**

**PHP 5.4.19 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2013 23:19:23)**

**nginx version: nginx/1.2.9**

**installed PHP-FPM: PHP 5.4.19 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Sep  3 2013 23:22:01)**

phpinfo() is working

**pma.nginx.conf:**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name pma.my.server;

root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
index index.php;
charset UTF-8;

access_log /var/log/myserver/pma.access.log;
error_log /var/log/myserver/pma.error.log;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  php-fpm;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```

}

**/var/log/myserver/pma.error.log:**

```
[error] 21374#0: *13 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 1.0.255.202, server: pma.my.server, request: "GET /js/get_image.js.php?theme=pmahomme HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "pma.my.server", referrer: "http://pma.my.server/"
```

**/var/log/php-fpm/error.log**

```
NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 21598
NOTICE: ready to handle connections
WARNING: [pool www] child 21600 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 12.862493 seconds from start
NOTICE: [pool www] child 21614 started
WARNING: [pool www] child 21602 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 13.768522 seconds from start
NOTICE: [pool www] child 21617 started
```

**/var/log/messages**

```
kernel: [12499.658777] php-fpm[21603]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000005c5a39 sp 00007fffb44d6d60 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+31c000]
```

I don't have big experience with Nginx and FastCGI, so I need your help. Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it appears that PHP is trying to write session data to disk in a directory that's not actually writable, namely `/var/lib/php/session`.

[Thanks to Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/questions/427596/phpmyadmin-having-problems-on-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-rhel-6/429445)

Comment: Cheers, I had to change permissions from root:apache to root:nginx. I recently updated installed packages, I think it reclaimed this permission when it updated httpd.

Comment: @BradMoore Very glad to help you)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is php unable to write session to file but it not necessarily located in `/var/lib/php/session`
You can check and change it by using `session_save_path`

Answer (score 1):

It appears there are a lot of things that can cause this, but if you are running a Magento website also check to see if any shopping cart rules were changed recently and see this [relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591074/385979). That was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code in this file `/js/get_image.js.php` cause segment fault.

You can use core dump to view the backtrace.

[Nginx Core dump](http://wiki.nginx.org/Debugging)