# Nginx + PHP-FPM 502 Bad Gateway, code igniter log says: Final output sent to browser

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, php

I have a Code Igniter, in it's logs says: `Final output sent to browser`.
The response is a PNG file.

But Nginx reports:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

and php-fpm says:

```
[WARNING] [pool www] child 17427 exited on signal 11 SIGSEGV after 14.657176 seconds from start
```

There is nothing else in logs that would help me. What would you do to help track down the issue?

Comment: Did you shut down the browser before the PNG stream ended?

Comment: Do you know what code causes this or is that yet to be determined? Errors like these are difficult to hunt down, you have something causing a segfault. What do you have in your app that can run for a long time and send lots of data while writing to memory? I'd start there.

Comment: The process finishes in 0.100 seconds. It's an image api, and there is not much else to check, as this is the only call.

Comment: Then it's time to investigate whether that image API works as it should and whether there are any potential holes that can cause a segfault. That's why, without code, it's all guessing.

Comment: it all works fine under Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by checking logs (which you did -- did you check `log/messages` though?).

Then I'd search the google:

https://serverfault.com/q/427596/38936
[Nginx + php-fpm on Amazon Linux = exited on signal 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18947495/183254)
https://serverfault.com/a/523851/38936

Which would lead me to

http://wiki.nginx.org/Debugging

Which would lead me to researching gbd and APC and tracing nginx stack.

Doesn't look like a simple issue. Some type of memory problem. Lot's of talk about disabling APC/op-cache and/or mishandling of sessions.
I would then do a little more research and balk at recompiling nginx to enable debugging. I'd change around my google queries and eventually come to

https://serverfault.com/a/410771/38936

which states that there is a [serious bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62205) in php 5.3.14 which doesn't work well with php-fpm. If that didn't work, I'd head over to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20637898/183254) and ask a question.

Comment: we have PHP 5.3.3, log/messages shows `php-fpm[22758]: segfault at 10 ip 00000000005c870f sp 00007fff9337d0d0 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+2d3000]`, session directory checked, it's writable.