# Magento 502 Bad gateway, only on configurable products

Tags: magento, error-handling

I am receiving a 502 bad gateway error but only on configurable products. Below is the ngnix log.

We are running Magento 1.9.1.0 with all plugins disabled and this error still occurs with the default theme.

```
2015-01-23 11:49:21 UTC 2015/01/23 11:49:21 [error] 5393#0: *14926882 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.45.678.912, server: mywebsite.co.uk, request: "POST /checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2Rldi50b3dlci1oZWFsdGguY28udWsvY2lyY3VsYXRpb24tcHJvLmh0bWw,/product/762/form_key/R7HvodwFx4M1C0hR/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php5-fpm-usernm.sock:", host: "dev.mywebsite.co.uk", referrer: "http://dev.mywebsite.co.uk/product.html"
```

The PHP errors are as follows...

```
child 15937 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 29.994150 seconds from start

child 16194 started
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Unable to comment due to low points)

Anyway, we had this issue as well with configurable products, and it turned out to be an issue with one of our product price rules. We are running Enterprise edition, and Magento provided us with a patch. I'm not sure if the CE version has a support team available or not though.

I would check your shopping cart rules and try determining if one of them is the culprit by disabling the rules one at a time.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have A LOT of cart rules so I just deleted them all on my dev site and that seems to have fixed the issue!

Comment: Do you know which patch # this is, so my team can request it from Magento?  We're having the same issue

Comment: @Navarr, I believe it's patch #5188 as that's the only patch in my notes that mentions configurable products.

Comment: @matr07 Yes it is!  Thank you :)  Fixed my problem too.

Comment: @matr07 I installed v2 which has a regression in it, you might want to know.  Shopping Cart Rules based on QTY stop working on configurables with that patch.  I've sent an email to support, but basically ->setQty($object->getQty()) looks like it needs to be added to Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine::validate around line 226.

Comment: @Navarr, Thanks for the info. We have another patch 4814 which we have listed as "Shopping Cart Rule issue regarding cart conditions and product categories" in our spreadsheet. I don't know if this would fix what you mention above or not. As you can see the description we wrote for this wasn't too detailed :)

Answer (score 3):

This may be linked to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37395/magento-debug-trace/44112#44112

Configurable products would throw a 502 Bad Gateway when adding to cart. Was linked to a Shopping Cart Rule that included a subselection of products.

Implemented the following solution:

```
app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Subselect.php on approx line 114:

**From:** if (parent::validate($item)) {

**To:** if (Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine::validate($item)) {
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. I was pulling my hair whole day :(